# Javascript incrementation issue

Tags: javascript

```
for (i = 1; i <= arrayNum; i++) { 
    $(".totalCubesBoards"+i+"").val(result.test1);
}
```

My goal .val(result.test[i]); it does not work brings NaN

Hello I have this code, I found a vay how to increment $(".totalCubesBoards"+i+"") but when I try to increment .val(result.test1) by any way (for example: (result.test+i); or (result.test+Number(i));) it simply does not work.

arrayNum brings = 2 it works.
if you do result.test1 = it works
result is ajax success , test comes from php after calculation

Any ideas or answers would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of "numbering" variable names, use an array.

Comment: if you are using class concept `.totalCubesBoards` then no need to do increment things because in jquery you can work with that single class itself.  Also can you show what is the value of `console.log(result);`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kmksg0da/

in php 
 $test = array();
 $passedArray = $_POST['arrayNum'];

 $numberOfLines = $passedArray;

 $i = 1;

 for ($i; $i <= $numberOfLines ; $i++) { 
  $calculation[$i]=$_POST['calculation'. $i];
  $test['test'. $i] = array_product($calculation[$i])/1000000000;
 }

 echo json_encode($test);

I need to increment result.test so I could pass value to totalCubesBoards incremented classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has to do with how you are accessing the object of result. You might want to try `result["test" + i]`. See if that works.

UPDATE: I tested it out in REPL.it and it works as expected

```
const result = { test1: 1, test2: 2, test3: 3}

for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  const val = result["test" + i]
  console.log(val)
}
```

The console then logs out:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for taking time answering this one. unfortunately it does not work because it should be result.test and after that I need somehow to increment this so it should be something like this .val(result.test + i); but it does not work like that

Comment: If you are saying that the first execution does not need an increment, you can pass a simple `if` statement: `if (i === 0) { $(".totalCubesBoards"+i+"").val(result.test);  }` else `$(".totalCubesBoards"+i+"").val(result["test" + i]);` Also putting `.val(result.test + i)` will not work because you are not accessing the property correctly of result.

Comment: Hey Adam, I was stupid, thank you for your time. It totally solved my issue. You are genius. Have a great day, Sir. :)